# How to use vite-plugin-favicons-inject package in a laravel+inertia+vue project?

Tags: laravel, vuejs3, vite, favicon, inertiajs

I tried to use this code in a laravel+inertia+vue project.

my vit.config.js (in root folder):

```
import { defineConfig } from 'vite';
import laravel from 'laravel-vite-plugin';
import vue from '@vitejs/plugin-vue';
import vitePluginFaviconsInject from 'vite-plugin-favicons-inject';

export default defineConfig({
    plugins: [
        laravel({
            input: 'resources/js/app.js',
            refresh: true,
        }),
        vue({
            template: {
                transformAssetUrls: {
                    base: null,
                    includeAbsolute: false,
                },
            },
        }),
        vitePluginFaviconsInject('resources/img/logo/rosesefid.png'),
    ],
});
```

that facing the following error :

```
error during build:
Error: NO_FILES_FOUND
    at Object.closeBundle (C:\laragon2\www\alomoshaver\node_modules\vite-plugin-favicons-inject\dist\cjs\index.js:94:15)
    at file:///C:/laragon2/www/alomoshaver/node_modules/rollup/dist/es/shared/node-entry.js:24343:40
    at process.processTicksAndRejections (node:internal/process/task_queues:95:5)
    at async Promise.all (index 0)
    at async PluginDriver.hookParallel (file:///C:/laragon2/www/alomoshaver/node_modules/rollup/dist/es/shared/node-entry.js:24271:9)
    at async Object.close (file:///C:/laragon2/www/alomoshaver/node_modules/rollup/dist/es/shared/node-entry.js:25573:13)
    at async build (file:///C:/laragon2/www/alomoshaver/node_modules/vite/dist/node/chunks/dep-ca21228b.js:44680:13)
    at async CAC.<anonymous> (file:///C:/laragon2/www/alomoshaver/node_modules/vite/dist/node/cli.js:813:9)
```

Also I tried the following path with no success and same error:

`../img/logo/rosesefid.png`
`./resources/img/logo/rosesefid.png`
`/resources/img/logo/rosesefid.png`

What should be the path of the logo?